# Reusable PHP file with different MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I was curious if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am going to be using the same index.php file over and over and I didn't know if there is an easier way to update it with each new MySQL tables that I create. Was trying to save time and not have to search for every piece of code to change every time I reuse the index.php file.

I have the layout and design I want to reuse. Just need to update the php file to the new table.

I didn't know if this would use variables to do this or not.

If someone could just point me what to research or lookup I would appreciate it. I want to learn and don't mind doing the work.

Basically it would be as follows:

order/index.php
customer/index.php
etc.

I want to reuse the same HTML and php code but I just want to make it easier to change the SQl table when I create a new table for each one.

I hope this makes since.

Thank you.

Comment: little bit too general, consider looking at using a framework like laravel and most of the lower level things like creating tables, writing queries etc are handled.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Doing this with literal `.php` files is pretty antiquated. You're probably looking for a "router" which can map URLs to internal "controllers" as per the [MVC model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller) used by most frameworks.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and suggestions. This will give me somewhere to start and study on.

Comment: @tadman I think I am going to try CodeIgniter and study there to get me going. Thank you again sir.

Comment: Hope that works out! If you've got any questions there's a lot of people here who can [help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter).

Comment: Just to observe, lots of identical tables (if that's what we're talking about) can be symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: tadman Thank you again. I am trying to get this and do my studying. 

@strawberry, Only the php and html side will stay the same. There will be a new table with different fields for each. I am just trying to make a default template to save time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a simple template file system with PHP.

In your `template.php` you should have something like

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
  ...
  <?php include $content; ?>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

Then before you include `template.php` you assign `$content` variable to a filename or a path such as `order.php` or `customer.php` etc. With this everything in your `template.php` plus the file that is included will be shown.

Comment: Technically, sure, but this style of coding proved to be hugely problematic over 20 years ago, so...

Comment: @tadman you are right, but I assume op is still learning or experimenting so router and such is a bit too magical.

Comment: You either spend the time to learn how to use a router and reap the rewards, or you do it this way and make a miserable mess that you may never be able to clean up. I know you're trying to help, but this method is nothing but chaos and confusion.

Comment: @anurat thank you for sharing the above. I do want to learn the correct way and don't want to make a mess of the code. I prefer putting the time in to learn. Again thank you for the information you shared and taking the time to reply. I appreciate it.